# ANDROID SDK NOT SHOWING OPTION TO DOWNLOAD ANDROID SDK COMMAND-LINE TOOLS AND ANDROID STUDIO IS NOT UPDATING

Tags: flutter, android-studio, sdk, android-sdk-manager

I had to download command line tools for flutter. I had downloaded them but version was old so I deleted it directly from local disk C and now I am trying to download from android studio but I cannot find the option to download it.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CrpBv.png)

I tried updating android studio but this error came

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f4d5m.png)
althoug my HTTP proxy settings are No proxy
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dKAUw.png)

What is the problem here please help!

Comment: https://developer.android.com/tools#tools-sdk

Comment: Please don't use all-caps - it's widely regarded as the internet equivalent of shouting.